# Assigning numeric vector in RcppEigen

Tags: c++, r, eigen, rcpp, rcppeigen

I have a cpp file which contains the code as below:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

using namespace Eigen;


//[[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::VectorXd memory(const double u, const double v, const double w){
  Eigen::VectorXd A(3);
   A << u,v,w;
return(A); 
}
```

But it shows me this error in the command (Please see the attached screenshot). [image: Error in code]

The whole R session ABORTS because of this. Why this is happening? Can anyone help? How can I write this numeric vector properly?

Comment: Hijacking this post as you [deleted the one we've been having an exchange on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72945108/specifying-parameter-matrix-cells-in-r-stan); I recommend defining a triangular matrix. Unfortunately from what I know, Stan does not (yet) directly support triangular data types; here is a [relevant post on the Stan discourse](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/lower-upper-triangular-matrix-data-types/4361/9).

Comment: @MauritsEvers haha...thank you. Will look into it. I lost a lot of points for posting ambiguous "words", which is why I deleted the other post. :) Guilty !!!

Answer (score 1):

Rcpp and RcppEigen are *glue packages* and may have a side effect on existing components.  So the `<<` idiom used to assign a matrix may be in the Eigen docs but may get shadowed by the Rcpp input/output ops.

In another note, your title is a little off.  This does not 'write', you were trying to assign.  Which ... you can do more easily from R directly as in this example:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void showVec(Eigen::VectorXd A) {
    Rcpp::Rcout << A << std::endl;
}

/*** R
v <- c(1.1, 2.2, 3.3)
showVec(v)
*/
```

which we can call from R and have the bottom portioned executed if we just call `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` on it:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/68453452/answer.cpp")    

# lots of compiler noise omitted here


> v <- c(1.1, 2.2, 3.3)

> showVec(v)
1.1
2.2
3.3
>
```

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks. But since this (shadowing) is the problem; how can I assign values to a numeric vector in RcppEigen? This portion is a smaller portion of a much larger code. I need to do this in order to do a double integral. Or, can I convert a Rcpp::NumericVector to a Eigen::VectorXd ?

Comment: You can always separate your functions into different files, only include `RcppEigen.h` in the files having _interface_ functions, but keep pure Eigen code with only Eigen headers.  Also note that there are other methods of assigning matrix and vector objects.

Comment: Can you give some examples of assigning vector objects in Eigen? Because when I try to access the vector (Eigen::VectorXd) element like A[0]=u; it shows another error; which is - "subscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector".  @Dirk

Comment: A few things here.  First off, as I first suggested, splitting over different files with different headers will work. Second, I actually looked at their docs as well and it looks dire.  Then again, you can always use proper C++11 or later for brace initializers to a std::vector and then make an Eigen object from that, similar to what we do when we pass R objects.  Or do as generally I do ... and stick to Armadillo.  Thirdly, your last comment implies a simple-ish C++ error on your side. Maybe look at existing RcppEigen examples here, on CRAN, or at the Rcpp Gallery ?  Good luck!